# Azure LB not routing traffic to VMs

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

I have two VMs in the backend pool of the load balancer. I have set up the health probe to probe port 80. The network security groups on both VMs allow 80 from any source and any protocol. I've also setup NAT rules for SSH to both VMs, and I can SSH normally. I can load port 80 by connecting to the individual IP's of both VMs.

Loading the load balancer IP (or URL) just leaves me hanging, the traffic doesn't hit my VMs at all.

I followed this tutorial to setup the Azure LB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-portal

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check if your VMs are responding on port 80. VM firewall could be blocking the traffic

Comment: @BrunoFaria `I can load port 80 by connecting to the individual IP's of both VMs.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, we should check LB **Backend pools** settings and **Health probes** settings.

1.Check backend pools:

After we add VMs to backend pool successfully, we can find them via Azure portal, like this:

[image]

2.Check LB health probe settings:

If we have not configure the health status in web server(**Linux**), we should use default settings, like this:

[image]

By the way, we can enable logging in **Diagnostics logs** for Azure load balancer, we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log) to enable it.

We will see the **Health probe log** like this(example):

```
{
    "records":[
    {
        "time": "2016-01-26T10:37:46.6024215Z",
        "systemId": "32077926-b9c4-42fb-94c1-762e528b5b27",
        "category": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX/RESOURCEGROUPS/RG7/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.NETWORK/LOADBALANCERS/WWEBLB",
        "operationName": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "properties": {
            "publicIpAddress": "40.83.190.158",
            "port": "81",
            "totalDipCount": 2,
            "dipDownCount": 1,
            "healthPercentage": 50.000000
        }
    },
    {
        "time": "2016-01-26T10:37:46.6024215Z",
        "systemId": "32077926-b9c4-42fb-94c1-762e528b5b27",
        "category": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX/RESOURCEGROUPS/RG7/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.NETWORK/LOADBALANCERS/WWEBLB",
        "operationName": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "properties": {
            "publicIpAddress": "40.83.190.158",
            "port": "81",
            "totalDipCount": 2,
            "dipDownCount": 0,
            "healthPercentage": 100.000000
        }
    }]
}
```

---

**Update**:

When we add LB backend pool, we should select VM NIC, like this:

[image]

Comment: I have those same settings for my LB, except that I have 2 VMs in the backend pool. I presume there is no other way to troubleshoot this except for enabling diagnostics, for which I need another addition to the subscription first. I'll report back once I've set up that one as well.

Comment: Probe path is `/`?

Comment: Could you show me your Probe setting screenshot and LB rules screenshot here?

Comment: Sure! Here's the LB probe settings: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9jncka_I9PXoI1EFgN6Fh3qoToa_iSH/view and the LB rules: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PuuOUxuyj_zuEIjQy3ddV3aAyLf6jWpV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you mean you can use VM's public IP address to browse it?

Comment: Correct. Each VM has it's own IP address, and loading it in a browser, pinging it, SSH-ing to it (directly and via the LB NAT rule) works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162875/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-vedran).

Comment: did you have to do anything with your firewall rules? I've looked at the chat and I have the same problem even when I have added the target network configurations